# Using Python schedule module at certain times, but first run tends to run multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, schedule

I am running a schedule set to execute a function every 5 seconds between start_time and end_time. However, the first instance it runs tends to run multiple times. Why is this, how is the timing handled? Sample code below

```
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime

def job():
    print(f'Hello world {time.ctime()}')

start_time = datetime.strptime("10:00", "%H:%M").time()
end_time = datetime.strptime("11:00", "%H:%M").time()

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    current_time = datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)
    if start_time <= current_time < end_time:
        schedule.run_pending()
    else:
        print('outside working hours')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have tried rounding the current time to nearest second. I expected the job to run only once for the first time - why is it running multiple times, what is happening with the timing?